# Git doesn't track folders

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I am trying to track my dotfiles and config folders with git.
I set up my `.gitignore` to ignore all (*) but the files and folders I want to track:

```
### Gitignore
# ignore all
**
!**/
# but...
# files
!.vimrc
!.Xdefault
!.bashrc
!.profile
!.xsession
!.gitignore
# folders
!.vim/**
!.config/i3/**
!.config/ranger/**
```

This however works only for the files, not for folders.
If I try to manually add a folder (eg. `git add .config/i3`) I get `The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files: .config/i3 Use -f if you really want to add them`.

Comment: Side note: Git *never* tracks a folder / directory, it only has tracked and untracked *files*. Directories are pesky things that Git just creates if and when it needs to in order to stick a file in there—i.e., if the file `a/b/c/d` is tracked, Git will `mkdir a; mkdir a/b; mkdir a/b/c` if and when necessary to write `a/b/c/d`. For performance reasons, Git *can* ignore—by which it means "not bother reading"—entire directories. Your `.gitignore` looks correct to me though!

Comment: @torek Yes, it does look good: it is mine. And I mentioned the folders not being tracked in the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore all: `**`, you need to whitelist folders *before* being able to exclude *files* (because if a folder is ignored, its content won't be examined for exclusion)

So:

```
**
!**/
```

Then you can add files exclusions:

```
# but 
# files (eg)
!.Xdefaults
!.vimrc
# etc
# folders (eg)
!./.vim/**
!./.config/ranger/**
!./.config/i3/**
```

Check with `git check-ignore -v -- a/file` that those rules do apply.

Comment: I added `**` and `!**/`. Now `git status` shows untracked files, among others the generic Downloads/,  but not the folders I want to track... I have no idea why it does that though.

Comment: @upgrd if you think Downloads/afile is being ignored, check it with `git check-ignore -v -- Downloads/afile ` (assuling Downloads/ is not an empty folder, since Git ignores empty folders anyway)

Comment: The Downloads/ folder is not being ignored, which is odd (given the above .gitignore).
The `git check-ignore -v` command you proposed interestingly shows that `.vim/**` is ignored because it matches the `**` pattern.. Somehow the negation bang (`!./.vim/**`) has apparently no effect.

Comment: @upgrd I just tested it: `git check-ignore -v -- .vim/a` returns: `.gitignore:3:!.vim/**   .vim/a`: so it is working.

Comment: @upgrd Can you edit your question with the exact content of your `.gitignore`?

Comment: I edited my question with the full .gitignore.

The fact that `git check-ignore -v ./.vim/` returns  `.gitignore:3:** ./.vim/` is the problem. I don't want .vim/ to be ignored, I want to track it and it's content..

Comment: @upgrd OK, but you forgot the folders whitelist: `!**/`

Comment: As I said, with both `**` and `!**/` in place at the beginning of the file, `git status` returns `.config/`, `.fzf/`, `.vim/` and `Downloads/` as 'untracked files' ...

Comment: @upgrd I meant: I don't see `!**/` in the .gitignore you mention in the edited question.

Comment: @upgrd But if you do have that `!**/`, try first: `git rm --cached -r Downloads/`, then check your `git status` again.

Comment: `git rm --cached -r Downloads/` returns `fatal: pathspec 'Downloads/' did not match any files`.

Comment: @upgrd I am assuming here that you have a .git in your $HOME, and that Download is a direct subfolder of your $HOME.

Comment: @upgrd But again, I still don't see  `!**/` in the `.gitignore` you mention in the edited question.

Comment: sry for the confusion, I had the `!**/` on my system, but didn't update it in the post.. 

Yes, I have a .git directory in my $HOME and yes, Download is a direct subfolder! 
The plan was/is: `git init` in $HOME, gitignore `**` but the files to track, track the selected dotfiles and push to github.

Comment: @upgrd And that plan can work, with the .gitignore I mentioned. Is the Downloads folder empty? What is your version of Git? What is your OS, and OS version?

Comment: No, the Downloads/ folder is not empty. Git version is 2.7.4, OS is Trisquel GNU/Linux 8.0

Comment: @upgrd First things first, upgrade to Git 2.19

Comment: @upgrd I wasn't born when Git 2.7 was out. The universe itself barely left the bing-bang phase, the... the point is: a lot of bugs have been fixed the the old antiquated obsolete 2.7 version.

Comment: wtf! I installed git via apt repository and didn't think about anything, as it turned out you need actually a ppa to install the latest git version on Trisquel! :D

However, my problems remain.. :(

Comment: @upgrd Yes, ppa as in https://trisquel.info/en/forum/update-git-trisquel-7. Do you have Git 2.19 now?

Comment: yes, git 2.19.0 is installed, but nothing improved.

Comment: @upgrd I just tested on my side: I can add .config/i3/afile, without any issue.